# border для div на jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем привет, такая задача:

Нужно чтобы при клике на один из блоков ("тарифов") тому добавлялся класс `.active` и у блока появлялась рамка. При этом нажав на другой блок, рамка с прошлого убиралась. С помощью jQuery.

У меня в голове только одно решение: каждому блоку дать отдельный класс - но это ведь неправильно, ибо слишком много кода. А если добавить `.active` в класс `.plan__blocks__block` то рамка будет у всех блоков, разве нет?

Спасибо.

```css
.plan__blocks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.plan__blocks__block {
  height: 448px;
  width: 231px;
  margin: 0 1.25px;
}

.plan__blocks__block__lower {
  height: 320px;
  background: #1f282c;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.plan__blocks__block__lower p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}



.plan__blocks__block__lower a {
  background: #f6744b;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 21px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.active {
  border: 1px solid #f6744b;
}
```

```html
<div class="plan__blocks">
  <div class="plan__blocks__block">
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__title">
      <h3>Basic</h3>
      <p>Free</p>
    </div>
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__lower">
      <p><span>20</span> Pages</p>
      <p><span>2</span> GB Storage</p>
      <p><span>150</span> Members</p>
      <p><span>2</span> Contributors</p>
      <a href="#">Purchase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="plan__blocks__block">
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__title">
      <h3>Standart</h3>
      <p><span>$</span>24.00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__lower">
      <p><span>25</span> Pages</p>
      <p><span>10</span> GB Storage</p>
      <p><span>300</span> Members</p>
      <p><span>5</span> Contributors</p>
      <a href="#">Purchase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="plan__blocks__block">
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__title">
      <h3>Premium</h3>
      <p><span>$</span>40.00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__lower">
      <p><span>30</span> Pages</p>
      <p><span>20</span> GB Storage</p>
      <p><span>500</span> Members</p>
      <p><span>10</span> Contributors</p>
      <a href="#">Purchase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="plan__blocks__block">
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__title">
      <h3>Professional</h3>
      <p><span>$</span>75.00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__lower">
      <p><span>40</span> Pages</p>
      <p><span>40</span> GB Storage</p>
      <p><span>1000</span> Members</p>
      <p><span>20</span> Contributors</p>
      <a href="#">Purchase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".plan__blocks__block .plan__blocks__block__lower a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".plan__blocks").find(".plan__blocks__block.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).closest(".plan__blocks__block").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.plan__blocks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.plan__blocks__block {
  height: 448px;
  width: 231px;
  margin: 0 1.25px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.plan__blocks__block__lower {
  height: 320px;
  background: #1f282c;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.plan__blocks__block__lower p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}



.plan__blocks__block__lower a {
  background: #f6744b;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 21px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid #f6744b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plan__blocks">
  <div class="plan__blocks__block">
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__title">
      <h3>Basic</h3>
      <p>Free</p>
    </div>
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__lower">
      <p><span>20</span> Pages</p>
      <p><span>2</span> GB Storage</p>
      <p><span>150</span> Members</p>
      <p><span>2</span> Contributors</p>
      <a href="#">Purchase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="plan__blocks__block">
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__title">
      <h3>Standart</h3>
      <p><span>$</span>24.00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__lower">
      <p><span>25</span> Pages</p>
      <p><span>10</span> GB Storage</p>
      <p><span>300</span> Members</p>
      <p><span>5</span> Contributors</p>
      <a href="#">Purchase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="plan__blocks__block">
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__title">
      <h3>Premium</h3>
      <p><span>$</span>40.00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__lower">
      <p><span>30</span> Pages</p>
      <p><span>20</span> GB Storage</p>
      <p><span>500</span> Members</p>
      <p><span>10</span> Contributors</p>
      <a href="#">Purchase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="plan__blocks__block">
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__title">
      <h3>Professional</h3>
      <p><span>$</span>75.00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="plan__blocks__block__lower">
      <p><span>40</span> Pages</p>
      <p><span>40</span> GB Storage</p>
      <p><span>1000</span> Members</p>
      <p><span>20</span> Contributors</p>
      <a href="#">Purchase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```